# Flex-list: Icons above label fields, centered

Tags: apache-flex, list

I finally managed to make my list render horizontally but the problem is this:

When I run the app I see the list like this: [image: My list view (iPad)]

*Don't mind the label fields, the data is gathered from a testing XML*

The thing is, I want the list to show the icon above the label field (the iMac image above label 'file1') and The both to be centered.

Here is the list code in my HomeView:

```
<s:List id="tripList" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
        change="tripList_changeHandler(event)" dataProvider="{data}" horizontalCenter="0"
        labelField="title" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:IconItemRenderer iconFunction="getPhotoURL" iconWidth="128" iconHeight="128" height="150" width="379" verticalAlign="top" textAlign="center">
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        protected function getPhotoURL(item:Object):String
                        {
                            return "images/mine/" + item.image
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>
            </s:IconItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Thx for any answer!

Comment: +1 for a well structured question.  The gist is create your own custom itemRenderer to layout the elements the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this...

```
<s:List id="tripList" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
            horizontalCenter="0"
            labelField="title" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:Object title="item 1" icon="adobe-logo.jpg" />
                <fx:Object title="item 2" icon="adobe-logo.jpg" />
                <fx:Object title="item 3" icon="adobe-logo.jpg" />
                <fx:Object title="item 4" icon="adobe-logo.jpg" />
                <fx:Object title="item 5" icon="adobe-logo.jpg" />
                <fx:Object title="item 6" icon="adobe-logo.jpg" />
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:ItemRenderer>
                    <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center">
                        <s:Image source="{data.icon}" />
                        <s:Label text="{data.title}" />
                    </s:VGroup>
                </s:ItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>
```

Comment: This one works, but with quite a big problem... When I set the ItemRenderer's width eg. to 379 as I had in my example, the text/labelfield is right under the image, but the image isn't in the center of the ItemRenderer (the one object) image: http://www.image-share.com/upload/841/149.png

Comment: try `<s:Vgroup horizontalAlign="center" width="379">` or to be a little more dynamic `<s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" width="{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width/3}">` if you're looking for 3 columns

Comment: Yay! It works, thanks very much! Although the FlexGlobals doesn't seem to work don't know why, but it doesn't matter... Great thanks!

Comment: Or you can set width to 100% on the ItemRenderer and VGroup for any number of equally spaced columns (note: setting a minWidth may be a good idea as well). :)